# Elasticsearch Java API: Is there a way to generate mapping from a document?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I wrote an index that is just not working. I'd like to know if a way to generate a mapping (that I can later modify) exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GET new_index/_mapping` to see the mapping from this index in the Kibana.